# Keep check box checked after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have checkboxes as below in my rails app

```
<% if field["field_type"] == "checklist"%>
 <% templat = @custom_templates.select{|s| s["id"] == m["startup_field_template_id"]}.first%>
 <small>
   <% vals = field["options"].to_s.gsub(/[\[\"\]]/, '').split(',') %>
   <% vals.each do |v| %>
   <% if templat["option_multi"]%>
     <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <%= v %><br/>
   <% else %>
     <input type="checkbox" class="check" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <%= v %><br/>
   <% end %>
   <% end %>
 </small>
<% else %>
 n/a
<% end %>
```

I used below code to keep checked checkbox 'checked' after refreshing the page

```
<sript>
$(function(){
var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
$('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
</script>
```

But it keep all check boxes checked after refreshing the page. how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The selector you are using will set all checkbox input state, so you have to set the checked attribute to each input individually, also not that a better way to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is to use `setItem` and `getItem()` methods:

here is a snippet (it will not work here because its a sandbox check the fiddle) and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/jo107e4u/27/):

```js
$(function(){
  var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
  $('input').each(function(i, el) {
   //console.log(localStorage.input);
   test = (localStorage.getItem(`input-${i}`) === 'true') ? true: false;
   $(el).prop('checked', test || false);
  }); 
  
});
$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.setItem(`input-${$(this).index('input')}`, $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> checkbox
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> checkbox
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> checkbox
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> checkbox
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> checkbox
```